# Issue with Android application using .Net MAUI and onscreen keyboard

Tags: android, .net, maui

## Problem:

Users are unable to access all the information on a page when the onscreen keyboard is displayed while using an Android application developed with .Net MAUI. The information under the keyboard remains hidden and requires the user to hide the keyboard to access it.

XAML Code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestKeyPadIssue.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry Placeholder="H1"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="H2"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="H3"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="H4"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="H5"/>

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

This will result in a page that will not allow the user to scroll down to the "Click Me" button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: if you're going to answer your own question, post the answer using the answer function, do not include it in the body of the question

Comment: @Jason...Thank You. I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

To resolve this issue, add the following line of code to MainActivity.cs:

```cs
Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

Your MainActivity.cs code should resemble the following:

```cs
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize);
    }
}
```

This code adjusts the page's relative size to the available space when the keyboard is displayed and readjusts it when the keyboard is hidden, allowing the user to access all the information on the page.

I am posting the issue and the solution in hopes that this will save others time/effort.

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could mark your answer. That might help others with same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT ... I definitely will. I have to wait 2 days before I can mark my answer as "the answer"