Android Virtual Keyboard Hide Input Boxes at the Bottom of the Page Using Blazor Hybrid with MAUI
I am writing an Android mobile app in C# using Blazor Hybrid with .NET MAUI. Forms with input components (such as input, textarea, etc.) placed at the bottom of the page are hidden by the virtual keyboard when these components gain focus and the keyboard is displayed.
To address this issue, I have added whitespace at the bottom of the page using the following code
<div style="height: 33vh;"></div>
This allows the page to be manually scrolled up when a component is tapped and the keyboard is displayed. However, I am looking for a more dynamic solution.
How can I make the page or the specific component automatically scroll up above the virtual keyboard when it is displayed?

Are you using 100vh not 100% height? I believe 100vh allows for the keyboard.

I'm using 33vh and it allows space for the keyboard when it shows up. However, I have to manually roll up the page to uncover the input box.

Resolved by implementing solution found here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76000094/issue-with-android-application-using-net-maui-and-onscreen-keyboard?rq=2
